# Find the value Sumation

Tags: summation, logarithms

> We have to find the value of
> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty
>  \left[ \frac{3\ln(4k+2)}{4k+2} 
>        -\frac{\ln(4k+3)}{4k+3}
>        -\frac{\ln(4k+4)}{4k+4}
>        -\frac{\ln(4k+5)}{4k+5}
>  \right]
> $$

**My try:**

[image]

But I am stuck after that.

Comment: This is a Putnam 2017 B4 problem and he forgot the 3 in the first logarithm (it is reflected in his picture). Solutions are available online

Comment: Mathematica shows that the answer is $\ln^22$.

Answer (score 1):

The Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula says
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(k)}{k}=\frac12\log(n)^2+C+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)
$$

---

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^k\frac{\log(k)}k
&=2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(2k)}{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\log(k)}k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(2)+\log(k)}k-\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\log(k)}k\\
&=\frac12\log(n)^2+\log(2)\log(n)+\gamma\log(2)-\frac12\log(2n)^2+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)\\[9pt]
&\stackrel{n\to\infty}\to\gamma\log(2)-\frac12\log(2)^2
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
2\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^k\frac{\log(2k)}{2k}
&=4\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(4k)}{4k}-2\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\log(2k)}{2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(4)+\log(k)}k-\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\log(2)+\log(k)}k\\
&=\frac12\log(n)^2+\log(4)\log(n)+\gamma\log(4)\\
&-\frac12\log(2n)^2-\log(2)\log(2n)-\gamma\log(2)+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)\\[9pt]
&\stackrel{n\to\infty}\to\gamma\log(2)-\frac32\log(2)^2
\end{align}
$$

---

After computing the sums above, it turns out that the sum in the question is a bit simpler
$$
\begin{align}
\overbrace{\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\log(k)}k}^{\substack{+1\leftrightarrow0\pmod2\\-1\leftrightarrow1\pmod2}}
-\overbrace{2\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\log(2k)}{2k}}^{\substack{+2\leftrightarrow0\pmod4\\-2\leftrightarrow2\pmod4}}
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\log(2)}k\\
&=\log(2)^2
\end{align}
$$